# Is the expanded form of "UTC" ever spelled with an diæresis?

Tags: time, proper-nouns, diphthongs, homonyms, diaeresis

I've always seen "UTC" expanded as *Coordinated Universal Time*. In addition, both the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [Encyclopædia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/Coordinated-Universal-Time) entries, as well as pretty much every reference to it I've ever seen that I can remember, spells it as such.

However, I often write diphthongs with diæreses. And, although for most if not all **practical** purposes I think most people would understand quite clearly what I mean if I write it as *Coördinated Universal Time*, from a technical standpoint is it the same thing?

After all, *Coordinated Universal Time* is a proper noun, which means it has a more rigid linguistic identity than common nouns, which can have homonymic alternatives; proper nouns often are less likely to have as such.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think the convention of using diaeresis is fading; even old stalwarts like the New Yorker are using them less. As a consequence, I believe using diacritical marks in English, if it has any effect at all, will more likely serve to confuse than clarify. By a similar train of thought, I rarely if ever see UTC expanded at all.  It's one of those acronyms where everyone "knows what it means" but no one knows what it stands for. In a way, the unexpanded acronym is *the* standard symbol to indicate the timezone. It stands on its own, opaque and not subject to analysis.

Comment: That's fine, but I'm not asking whether anyone thinks I *should* use the diæresis; I'm asking if I *can* use it, in particular by virtue of its nature as a proper noun.

Comment: *The New Yorker* magazine would likely spell it "Coördinated", but I'd be quite surprised to encounter that spelling in any other US publication.  (But I see Dan Bron has already mentioned that.)

Comment: Yes. But usage does not necessarily imply adherence when it comes to a distinct morphological framework. I'm asking if you can \*technically\* still say *Coördinated Universal Time* is the same proper noun as *Coordinated Universal Time*, based on the definition of "proper noun". Whether the New Yorker does it or not is irrelevant; I'm asking a question of theoretical limitations here. Not empirical limitations.

Comment: @SarahofGaia There isn't morphological question here; just an orthographic one. And my sense is that your unease is well-placed. Proper nouns are fixed; dictated by their creators.  I personally hate having to write "*e. e. cummings*" or "*Yahoo! Answers*", but I have to, because that's how they're spelled.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I was using the generic definition of *[morphology](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/morphology)*, not the linguistic definition: **generic**: "The study of the forms of things, in particular", **linguistics**: "The study of the forms of words." Of course, now that I [look it up](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/orthography), *orthography* definitely seems like the better choice of words. Although frankly I'm not entirely sure why it's defined as the study of words, since not all morphemes are words.

Comment: And I'd agree. Could you put that point about proper nouns as an answer, so I can mark it as such?